# pinch to zoom on android canvas draws a line

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am implementing pinch to zoom on a drawing app, but when I zoom it draws a line. I know why this is happening (the structure of my onTouchEvent method) but I can't come up with a way around it. Can anyone help?

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

    //get x and y values of user touch
    float touchx = event.getX();
    float touchy = event.getY();
    boolean isScaling;

    if (event.getPointerCount() > 1){
        sgd.onTouchEvent(event);
        isScaling = true;
        return true;
    }
    switch (event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            drawPath.moveTo(touchx, touchy);
            drawPath.lineTo((touchx+1.0f), touchy); //enable drawing points 
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            drawPath.lineTo(touchx, touchy);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
            drawPath.reset();
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

edit: got it! also a not yet implemented drag feature...

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    //get x and y values of user touch
    float touchx = event.getX();
    float touchy = event.getY();

    if (event.getPointerCount() > 1){
        sgd.onTouchEvent(event);
        isScaling=true;
        return true;
    }

    else if (moving){
        switch (event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                oldx = touchx;
                oldy = touchy;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (isScaling == false){
                    tx = touchx-oldx;
                    ty = touchy-oldy;
                    //canvas.translate
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if(isScaling){
                    isScaling = false;
                }
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
    else{
        switch (event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                drawPath.moveTo(touchx, touchy);
                oldx = touchx;
                oldy = touchy;
                drawPath.lineTo((touchx+1.0f), touchy); //enable drawing points, silence during scaling somehow
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (isScaling == false){
                    drawPath.lineTo(touchx, touchy);
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if(isScaling){
                    isScaling = false;
                }
                else{
                    drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
                }
                drawPath.reset();
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }   
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Add your solution as an answer. +1 for figuring it out

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have a button that you press to turn drawing "on" and "off". If the button is selected, then the drawing events occur. If the button pressed again to be de-selected, then the MotionEvent case performs the scroll/zoom events. This is a UI technique certain apps like [Snapchat use](http://www.likeable.com/blog/2013/12/7-things-you-didnt-know-you-could-do-on-spapchat/) to allow user to switch between drawing and changing image filters.